# Filter the non repeating ids month wise

Tags: r

I have following data

```
id   date        price
1   2017-11-12   110
2   2017-11-10   150
4   2017-11-13   190
1   2017-11-01   120
3   2017-12-12   10
6   2017-12-21   170
6   2017-12-14   180
7   2017-12-12   140
```

I want to extract ids which are not repeating in month. The output should be a data frame that contain non repeating ids as shown below

```
id   date        price
2   2017-11-10   150
4   2017-11-13   190
3   2017-12-12   10
7   2017-12-12   140
```

Comment: What is the type of your variable date?

Comment: Date is in factor

Comment: @SushrutVyawahare Would be easiest if you shared your data with `dput()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ave` produces a vector with the number of the current row's `id` in the current row's year/month.  We use `subset` with that to keep only those which are 1.  No packages are used.

```
subset(DF, ave(id, format(date, "%Y-%m"), id, FUN = length) == 1)
```

This gives:

```
  id       date price
2  2 2017-11-10   150
3  4 2017-11-13   190
5  3 2017-12-12    10
8  7 2017-12-12   140
```

### Note

We assume this input:

```
Lines <- "id   date        price
1   2017-11-12   110
2   2017-11-10   150
4   2017-11-13   190
1   2017-11-01   120
3   2017-12-12   10
6   2017-12-21   170
6   2017-12-14   180
7   2017-12-12   140"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
DF$date <- as.Date(DF$date)
```